# How to pass TextView values between three activities in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I want to build a user SignUp Application with four activities. (See in the pictures). The problem is, how can i save the textField values from activity one, two, and three to use the values in a method in the fourth activity?

[image: Activity1]

[image: Activity2]

[image: Activity1]

[image: Activity1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many ways to do this

(1) Set static global string and save username into it and use wherever you want

```
public static String USERNAME;

USERNAME = editText().getText().toString();
```

(2) Using SharedPreferences

Save string:

```
String username = editText.getText().toString();

PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("USERNAME", username).apply();
```

Get saved string wherever you want:

```
String username = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("USERNAME", "");
```